# How to access user explorer data in google analytics using Google analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to access User Explorer data using Google analytics API to get the report as JSON value. Using this JSON value I can create my web application dashboard for analytics. I couldn't found any metrics and dimensions to get User Explorer details in this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Please share if any related documents or any links to access User Explorer data using Google analytics API

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access the user explorer report via the API. Google has decided not to make this data available.

You might roll your own solution. For that you need two custom dimensions.

One is the client id, and you can see how to get this in this [incomplete answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044331/google-analytics-user-explorer-get-user-report).

It is incomplete because it does not allow you to break down a visit by sessions. So you need a session id as custom dimension. Storing a session id is actually rather simple - send a random number to a session scoped custom dimension, so each session will, by definition,  contain only the last value you send along.

Now you can download clientId and sessionID plus your relevant metrics, and break down the clientID data  in some external software by sessionID.

This won't help you with data that has already been collected, and even on a moderately large site you will probably run into API limits pretty quickly, but with a free GA account it is the only way I can think of. With a GA 360 account you can use BigQuery to recreate the User Explorer report.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Eike Pierstorff, but I need the exact data in User Explorer as JSON , is there any other way to get it?

Comment: Eike is right; there simply is no way to get what you're looking for without implementing a series of custom dimensions, or actually paying for the service that Google provides.

Comment: @Wai technically, yes (Universal Analytics has not changed much). If you work in Europe,  the client id might be a considered a pseudonym under the FGDR which would make this legally dogdy.