# Bulk export individual user's JSON data from Google Analytics User Explorer

Tags: javascript, python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am planning to build a recommendation feature for my website based on past user behavior. My idea of achieving it was to analyse each user's journey using data from each individual user from Google Analytics User Explorer and feed it to the algorithm.

In Analytics when I go to User Explorer, click into an individual user and do export, it downloads in a perfectly formatted user-report-export.json file - exactly what I need. However, to teach my algorithm I need to feed at least 1000 user journeys on a regular basis, meaning that I would need to manually download those files 1000 times. Is there a way to download all those individual journeys nicely formatted in one json file? I tried to look everywhere but couldn't find any documentation which would give some more information on how to achieve it.

I'm comfortable with Javascript and Python so if there are scripting options possible, I would be happy to try them out too.

Comment: Have you tried going though the google analytics api?  you can export all of the data that way you will just have to build up what ever it is that the user report exports for you yourself as the api only understands dimensions and metrics.

Comment: I just found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567957/how-to-access-user-explorer-data-in-google-analytics-using-google-analytics-api that "Google has decided not to make this data available." @DalmTo, could you expand on your asnwer on how would I get the User Explorer data from user exports? Many thanks.